# hide component when route another page in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

in my react project inside the home page i have a notification component, when i route to another page and again visit home page I want to hide the notification component. How can I do this? please give some suggestions on how can i do it.

Comment: can you share any code ?

Comment: You can set a state to show and hide the notifications. As an example, you can initially set this state to false (set to false in useEffect or componentDidMount) or set a timeout to set the state false. So, you can display the notification only if it is true.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can we see some code that represents your specific problem? even a small example will help. Are you facing any error?   Also, please refer to this link (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it will help you ask more specific questions

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the state of the notification in the state of the component that have all pages routes, for example:

```
const [needsNotification, setNeedsNotification] = useState('true');


<Switch>
  <Route
    path={'/home'}
    render={<Home props={...props, needsNotification}} />
  />
  <Route
    path={'/another-page'}
    render={<AnotherPage props={...props, setNeedsNotification} />}
  />
<Switch/>
```

In the AnotherPage component you use the function `props.setNeedsNotification(false)` when it mounts and in the home page you create a condition that the warning is only shown if `needsNotification === true`.